# Unable to unbond all the funds present in the locks

Tags: pallet-staking

I'm unbonding all the staking funds of the validators. After unbonding, all the funds are going to locked and they are moving into transferrable balance. But I'm able to transfer some funds from unbonding to transferrable but not whole amount. Can someone please guide me through this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your own private network, check if your existential deposit is set to zero, it will fail the [condition](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L106)`ledger.active < T::Currency::minimum_balance()`, here `minimum_balance` is existential deposit which will always return false and when you unbond all your funds it will only be parially unbonded.

Comment: thank you @shubham gupta

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the steps you have performed so far were using the Polkadot.js UI, then the guide to follow is [here](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000167902-how-can-i-unstake-my-tokens-again-). It is very thorough, you just have to make sure you follow every relevant step it mentions.

For example, if you wanted to unbond all your staked tokens then you would have:

- Clicked the "Stop" button to stop nominating with your account (to chill).
  After you click the "Stop" button you need to follow the step to start unbonding your tokens by, then by;
- Clicking the "Unbond funds" button, and then waiting for the unbonding period until they will be unbonded (28 days on Polkadot, 7 days on Kusama), which is when the countdown timer icon should disappeared, then lastly;
- Click the "Withdraw Unbonded" button after the unbonding period has finished to fully withdraw the tokens so it removes the lock icon and they become transferable.